# Custom iOS 7 Interactive Pop Animation goes blank after animating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

I am recreating the UINavigationController Push animation using the new iOS 7 custom transitioning APIs.

- I got the view pushing and popping fine using `animationControllerForOperation`
- I added a edge gesture recogniser for the interactive pop gesture.
- I used a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` subclass and integrated code from [WWDC 2013 218 - Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/)
- It looks like it removes the fromViewController by mistake, but I don't know why.
- The steps are:

  1. Interactive pop starts
  2. Finger is lifted after a short distance - red screenshot
  3. The view animates back a short distance.
  4. Red view is removed (I think) - black screenshot.

[image]
[image]

[The full code is on GitHub](https://github.com/rsaunders100/TestInteractiveTransition/tree/master/TestInteraceve), but here are 2 parts which I guess are important.

#### [Gesture delegate](https://github.com/rsaunders100/TestInteractiveTransition/blob/master/TestInteraceve/RSTransitionController.m#L74)

```
- (void)didSwipeBack:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)edgePanGestureRecognizer {

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.isInteractive = YES;
        [self.parentNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    if (!self.isInteractive) return;

    switch (state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            // Calculate percentage ...
            [self updateInteractiveTransition:percentagePanned];
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {

            if (state != UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled &&
                isPannedMoreThanHalfWay) {
                [self finishInteractiveTransition];
            } else {
                [self cancelInteractiveTransition];
            }

            self.isInteractive = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol](https://github.com/rsaunders100/TestInteractiveTransition/blob/master/TestInteraceve/RSTransitionController.m#L139)

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // Grab views ...

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];

    // Calculate initial and final frames        

    toViewController.view.frame = initalToViewControllerFrame;
    fromViewController.view.frame = initialFromViewControllerFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:RSTransitionVendorAnimationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        toViewController.view.frame = finalToViewControllerFrame;
        fromViewController.view.frame = finalFromViewControllerFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

Anyone know why the screen is blank? Or Can anyone point me to some sample code.  Apple don't appear have any sample code for interactive transitions using the percent driven interactions.

Comment: Why are you popping your view controller at the moment `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` instead of `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`?

Comment: @ismailgulek That's how interactive transitions work.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue was a bug in the Apple sample code that I copied.  The `completeTransition` method should have a more intelligent BOOL parameter like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:RSTransitionVendorAnimationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        toViewController.view.frame = finalToViewControllerFrame;
        fromViewController.view.frame = finalFromViewControllerFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
```

Thanks to @rounak for pointing me to the [objc.io post](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html).

This then presented another issue relating to the animation.  The animation would stop, present a blank view and them carry on.  This was almost defiantly a UIKit bug.  The fix was to set the `completionSpeed` to 0.99 instead of 1.0. The default value is 1.0 so I guess that setting it to this doesn't do some side effect in their custom setter.

```
// self is a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition
self.completionSpeed = 0.99;
```

Comment: Hah, I didn't spot that you were always sending YES in completeTransition. Glad you got your issue sorted!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` subclass. I just create a new `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` object, hold a strong reference to it and return it in `interactionControllerForAnimationController` method.

[This link for interactive transitions](http://objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) is quite helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I was following the 218 WWDC where they suggest using a subclass.  I will give it a go as a plain object.